# How to be a Beat's partner application?

Tags: beatsmusic

I'm trying to develop a new Android Application using Beats API. How do i register my app as a partner application that way i can use the authentication meant for Privileged Application.

Comment: This link claims that the password end point is accessible only to partner applications (https://developer.beatsmusic.com/docs/read/getting_started/Privileged_Applications).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a vendor support question and not a programming question as defined in the [help] guidelines. Contact the vendor for information concerning licensing, registration, enrollment, pricing, or services available.

Comment: Actually, i saw a link in beat's web site and thats why i had tagged it as beatsmusic. [https://developer.beatsmusic.com/support]

Comment: Development questions are on-topic here. This isn't a development question. It's a registration question, which can only be addressed by the vendor. Please read what I wrote again; if you need more information, please visit the [help]. The vendor providing a link here means nothing; questions here must meet the guidelines here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outside of using the public API for independent development, we have a partner process. Please write to: beatsplatform@beatsmusic.com with a description of your application and we can start the conversation.